# Accuracy and error rate of example Siamese network in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, siamese-network

I have been following this example [here](https://keras.io/examples/mnist_siamese/) and I want to know how exactly this accuracy function works:

```
def compute_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
'''Compute classification accuracy with a fixed threshold on distances.
'''
    pred = y_pred.ravel() < 0.5
    return np.mean(pred == y_true)
```

As far as I know the output of the network in this case is going to be the distance between two pairs. So how can we calculate the accuracy in this case? What does the "0.5" threshold refers to? Also, how can I calculate the error rate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there are some gaps in the understanding of that example which needs to be filled first:

If you study the data preparation step (i.e. `create_pairs` method), you would realize that the positive pairs (i.e. pairs of samples belonging to the same class) are assigned a label of 1 (i.e. positive/true) and the negative pairs (i.e. pairs of samples belonging to different classes) are assigned a label of 0 (i.e. negative/false).

Further, the Siamese network in the example is designed such that given a pair of samples as input it would predict their distance as output. By using the contrastive loss as the loss function of the model, the model is trained such that given a positive pair as input a small distance value is predicted (because they belong to the same class and therefore their distance should be low, i.e. to convey similarity) and given a negative pair as input a large distance value is predicted (because they belong to difference classes and therefore their distance should be high, i.e. to convey dissimilarity). As an exercise, try to confirm these points by considering them numerically (i.e. when `y_true` is 1 and when `y_true` is 0) using contrastive loss definition in the code.

So, the accuracy function in the example is implemented such that a fixed *arbitrary* threshold, i.e. 0.5, is applied on predicted distance values, i.e. `y_pred` (this means the author of this example has decided that distance values of less than 0.5 indicate positive pairs; you may decided to use another threshold value, but it should be a reasonable choice based on experiment/experience). Then the result would be compared with true label values, i.e. `y_true`:

- When `y_pred` is lower than 0.5 (`y_pred < 0.5` would be equal to `True`): if `y_true` is 1 (i.e. positive) then this means the prediction of the network is consistent with the true label (i.e. `True == 1` is equal to `True`) and therefore the prediction for this sample is counted towards correct predictions (i.e. accuracy). However, if `y_true` is 0 (i.e. negative) then the prediction for this sample is not correct (i.e. `True == 0` is equal to `False`) and therefore this would not contribute to correct predictions.
- When `y_pred` is equal or greater than 0.5 (`y_pred < 0.5` would be equal to `False`): Same reasoning as above applies (left as an exercise!).

(**Note:** don't forget that the model is trained on batches of samples. Therefore, `y_pred` or `y_true` are not a single value; rather, they are arrays of values, and all the calculations/comparisons mentioned above are applied element-wise).

Let's look at an (imaginary) numerical example on an input batch of 5 sample pairs and how the accuracy is calculated for predictions of the model on this batch:

```
>>> y_pred = np.array([1.5, 0.7, 0.1, 0.3, 3.2])
>>> y_true = np.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0])

>>> pred = y_pred < 0.5
>>> pred
array([False, False,  True,  True, False])

>>> result = pred == y_true
>>> result
array([False,  True, False,  True,  True])

>>> accuracy = np.mean(result)
>>> accuracy
0.6
```

Comment: I am using this function to calculate accuracy. Is my approach correct?  pred = y_pred.ravel() <= 0.6
return accuracy_score(y_true,pred)

Comment: @AtheerAbdullatif Yes, that's also a correct way of computing the accuracy. The `sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_true, pred)` is exactly the same as `np.mean(pred == y_true)`.

Comment: I honestly appreciate it. I am looking now into ways to define the threshold of the accuracy I thought of using ROC but the thing is I still have to define a threshold before passing the predicted labels to the ROC :    pred = y_pred.ravel() <= 0.6
    fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y_true, pred)

Comment: @AtheerAbdullatif I think you should find it experimentally, i.e. try different thresholds and see which one works best on validation/test data.